# Should I use %TYPE references instead standard data type in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Should I use %TYPE references instead of standard data type if I have over 200 tables in my database?

Is it decrease performance when I use %TYPE compare with standard data type?

I am new to Oracle and maybe this question so basic but I think it's very important for newbie like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TYPE keyword is resolved at compile time and has no bearing on performance.

You should strive to use it where you can, because it creates flexibility in your stored programs and objects. When the referenced object changes and the program that references it does so with a TYPE reference, then the change is automatically available to the caller - it is simply recompiled and the new definition is used. With a non-TYPE reference, your program could break because the defined type of a field becomes too large for the referenced column.

For example, if I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE A (I1 INTEGER, C1 VARCHAR2(10));
```

I have a stored procedure that reads from that table:

```
PROCEDURE P
  var  VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT C1 INTO var FROM A WHERE I1 = 1;
END;
```

This works, until such time as you modify the length of the column:

```
ALTER TABLE A MODIFY C1 VARCHAR2(20);
```

Now you could get an error from your select.

If you write the procedure this way:

```
PROCEDURE P
  var  A.C1%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT C1 INTO var FROM A WHERE I1 = 1;
END;
```

Then your code is immune, as Oracle will recompile the procedure when you run it, detecting the TYPE reference.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer! DCookie.